# Number of roots $f(x)(\log(f(x)))^\prime$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, roots

EDIT: I am interested in derivative of a function $f(x)$. However, since the function is logarithmically convex/concave it is easier to analyze $\log f(x)$. Therefore, I rewrote the derivative and analyze the following product:
$$h(x)=f(x)g(x),$$ where $g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$, i.e., 
$$h(x)=f(x)(\log(f(x))^\prime.$$

---

I know that function $f(x)$ is positive and strictly increasing ($f^\prime(x)>0$) and furthermore logarithmically convex for $x<0$ and logarithmically concave for $x>0$, i.e., $g(x)>0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=0$ for $x=0$. Also, $g(x)$ is an even function.

Thus, I know that there is exactly one maximum of $g(x)$.

I would like to show that also the function $h(x)$ has exactly one maximum. Intuitively, since I multiply the function $g(x)$ which has exactly one maximum and is even with a function $f(x)$ which is increasing (and moreover, related to $g(x)$), the maximum can only be shifted but no other maxima can be created or disappear.

My approach was to take the derivative of $h(x)$ and look if I can find some $x_0$ such that for $x<x_0$ $h(x)^\prime > 0$ and for $x>x_0$, $h(x)^\prime<0$, i.e., $$h^\prime(x)=f^\prime(x)(\log f(x))^\prime+f(x)(\log f(x))^{\prime\prime}=0.$$

Clearly, the first part is always positive. The second part is positive for $x<0$ and negative for $x>0.$ 
My problem is that if I add these two things up, it can possibly become a mess with more roots, or can't it?

Am I missing some more properties which would guarantee this? Any hints or ideas how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between $h(x)$ and $f'(x)$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang There is no difference. I am interested in $f^\prime(x)$ indeed. However, $f(x)$ is pretty complicated function such that its derivative can be written as the product of $f(x)(\log f(x))^\prime$. Which I thought is easier to analyze.

Comment: This identity holds for all functions for which $\log f(x)$ makes sense and is differentiable, so don't expect it to tell you anything about your particular function $f$...

Comment: @Servaes one of the assumptions was that $f$ was strictly positive.

Comment: @Servaes Yes, $f(x)$ is strictly positive and strictly increasing. That's why I can take the logarithm.

Comment: $$\frac{d(\log f(x))}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\Rightarrow h(x)=f'(x)?$$

Comment: @Piquito Please see other comments. I am indeed intersted in $f^\prime(x)$, however, I have more information about $\log(f(x))^\prime$, so I thought that could help me more to analyze also $f^\prime(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
h(x)=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\,(\log f(x))=f(x)\,\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=f'(x).
$$
Since $f$ is logarithmically convex on $(-\infty,0)$ it is also convex. This means that $f'$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0)$. **Similarly, $f'$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.** This implies that $f'$ attains a maximum at $x=0$. However $f'$ could be constant on an interval around $x=0$. This would not happen $f$ were strictly logarithmically convex on $(-\infty,0)$ and strictly logarithmically concave on $(0,\infty)$

*Note*: the part in bold is false in general. Concavity implies log-concavity, but not the other way around.

Comment: Yes. The function $f(x)$ is pretty complicated function and I am indeed interested in its derivative, which can be written as the product of $f(x)(\log f(x))^\prime$.

Comment: I have added some more material to my answer.

Comment: I had a hunch that OP was overthinking things.

Comment: Unfortunately, $f^\prime$ is not decreasing on $(0, \infty)$. Only $(\log f(x))^\prime$ is.

Comment: Uuups! I did not realize that log-convexity and log-concavity don't work the same way. log-convex implies convex, but log-concave does not imply concave.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Unfortunately. And that's my whole question. How to prove that the maximum in $x=0$ of $(\log f(x))^\prime$ is shifted to the right in case of $f^\prime(x)$.